# How this for loop works?

Tags: c, loops

I am new to the C programming. I came across the for loop example.
I don't understand some part of the loop. Output is 8. I don't get how b is incremented till 4.

Here is my code:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 2;
int result = 0;

for(int count = 0; count != b; count++) {
    result = result + a;
}

printf("a times b is %i\n", result);

return 0;
```

Comment: Which part you didn't understood ? Its very simple I guess. This `count != b` i.e it comes out of loop when `2!=2` & till that times result is `8` i.e `count`->`0` : `0+4`,  `count`->`1` : `4+4` => `8`.

Comment: _I don't get how b is increamented till 4 ?_ No `b` doesn't change at all. To debug it keep one `printf()` statement inside loop & analyze. For e.g `printf("b = %d\n",b);`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the easiest thing to do is to get the program to explain itself:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int a = 4;
    int b = 2;
    int result = 0;

    for(int count = 0; count != b; count++) {
        printf("a = %3d, b = %3d, count = %3d, result = %3d\n", a, b, count, result);
        result = result + a;
        printf("a = %3d, b = %3d, count = %3d, result = %3d\n", a, b, count, result);
    }
    printf("a = %3d, b = %3d\n", a, b);

    printf("a times b is %i\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
a =   4, b =   2, count =   0, result =   0
a =   4, b =   2, count =   0, result =   4
a =   4, b =   2, count =   1, result =   4
a =   4, b =   2, count =   1, result =   8
a =   4, b =   2
a times b is 8
```

As you can see, `b` does not change. `count` changes and the loop is exited when `count` is equal to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `b` is not incremented, the variable `count` starts from `0` and incremented in the `for loop`. When the `count` variable becomes `2` the loop ends. So, the loop runs twice (count 0 and count 1) and the result is `4 + 4 = 8`.

Answer (score 0):

At first, `count = 0` which is not the same with `b = 2` and so the loop starts. By doing so, the first iteration of loop gives a result,

```
result = 0 + 4
```

Since the loop ends and `count` variable should proceed `count++` which means `count = count + 1`. Thus, `count = 0 + 1 = 1` where it is not the same valeu with `b = 2` again.

Proceed the loop again,

```
result = 4  + 4 # where the first number came from the result of first loop
```

Now `count++` makes `count = 2` which is now same value with `b = 2`. Then, the condition of the loop is not matched, `count != 2`, no further loop and print the value `result = 8`.

Comment: _print `count = 8` ?_ No, that's `result` variable not the `count`.

Answer (score 0):

## it will be executed 2 times

count= 0 ==> result=0+4 
and count =1 ==> result=4+4 ==> result=8
**when it will reach count= 2 the 2!=2 part will be false and we will exit the for loop**

Answer (score 0):

The loop runs only two times we can dry run the loop like that:
Initial values for variables: -> a = 4, b = 2, count = 0 and result = 0

```
loop first run -> 
count = 0
count != 2 -> that is ->  0 != 2  => true
result = result + a   ->  0 + 4  = 4

second run ->
count = 1 
count != b -> that is ->  1 != 2  => true
result = result + a   ->  4 + 4 = 8

third run ->
count = 2
count != b -> that is ->  2 != 2 => false 
stop loop. 
And the final resultent values are as follow: a= 4, b= 2 , count = 2 and result = 8
```